# PHP Uncaught Error: Call to a member function userRole() on null

Tags: php

I have a class called class Settings in Settings.php

```
    class Settings

{  public function UserRole($is_login = false){

        $default = ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'New user'];

        $user_role = $this->getUser($id);
        if( !$user_role )
            return $default;

else ... etc.}
}
```

The problem is, in my User.php, where I have this:

```
    use Settings;

class Helper_User extends \Zend_View_Helper_Abstract
{

public function mainNavigation($is_collapsed = false){
        $instance = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
      ...
        return $this->container();
    }

 public function container(){
        $newuser = $this->getNewUser();

        $html = "blabla";
        return $html;
    }
}
```

and anywhere I try to put this `$role = $this->Settings->UserRole();`

I have this error

> Uncaught Error: Call to a member function UserRole() on null.

Can you please help what is wrong here? Thanks.

Comment: Error seems quite clear, `$this->Settings` is null. (Not sure how the second code is related to all this)

Comment: Where did you provide any value for `$this->Settings`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ah ok, I found out that if I call it like this:

```
    $loggedUser = new Settings($this);
    $role = $loggedUser->UserRole();
```

then it is working fine. It did not worked if I did it like $this->Settings->UserRole();